# XSLT: Transform nested XML into Ruby Code

Tags: ruby, xml, xslt, code-generation

I have several XML files that I need to generate Ruby code for. The XML structure I have is as follows:

```
<acronym_list> 
   xmlns="http://www.example.com/xsds" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/xsds           
                       http://www.example.com/xsds/acronyms.xsd">
 <item>
   <metadata>
     <release>...</release>
     <id>...</id>
     <checkdigit>...<checkdigit>
     <status>...</status>
     <date_added>...</date_added>
     <date_modified>...</date_modified>
     <language>...</language>
     <license_url>...</license_url>
   </metadata>
   <info>
     <name>...</name>
   </info>
 </item>
</acronym_list>
```

In this case, we're talking about acronyms. The `item` elements (and their children) are repeated for each acronym I have in my list. I also have several files with a similar structure with the `info` element having more children.

The Ruby code I'm trying to get out would look like:

```
Module acronym_list
    def self.included(other)
        include SAXMachine
        SAXMachine.configure(other) do |c|
          c.element :metadata, :class => metadata
          c.element :info, :class => info
        end
    end

    class metadata
       include SAXMachine
       c.element :release
       c.element :id
       c.element :checkdigit
       c.element :status
       c.element :date_added
       c.element :date_modified
       c.element :language
       c.element :license_url
    end

    class info
       include SAXMachine
       c.element :name
    end           
end
```

The same pattern follows for the other XML files that I'm trying to parse. I've managed to get the first part working with the module declaration, but I don't know enough XSLT to get the rest.

Would somebody be able to help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the ruby syntax so I am not sure whether indentation or whitespace matters but with the stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:acs="http://www.example.com/xsds"
  exclude-result-prefixes="acs">

<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="acs:acronym_list">
Module <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
  def self.included(other)
     include SAXMachine
     SAXMachine.configure(other) do |c|
       <xsl:apply-templates select="acs:item/acs:*" mode="config"/>
     end
  end

  <xsl:apply-templates select="acs:item/acs:*" mode="class"/>
end
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="acs:item/acs:*" mode="config">
        c.element :<xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>, :class => <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
</xsl:template>  

<xsl:template match="acs:item/acs:*" mode="class">
  class <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
    include SAXMachine
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="class"/>
  end
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="acs:item/acs:*/acs:*" mode="class">
    c.element :<xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Saxon 6.5.5 tansforms the input

```
<acronym_list
   xmlns="http://www.example.com/xsds" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/xsds           
                       http://www.example.com/xsds/acronyms.xsd">
 <item>
   <metadata>
     <release>...</release>
     <id>...</id>
     <checkdigit>...</checkdigit>
     <status>...</status>
     <date_added>...</date_added>
     <date_modified>...</date_modified>
     <language>...</language>
     <license_url>...</license_url>
   </metadata>
   <info>
     <name>...</name>
   </info>
 </item>
</acronym_list>
```

into the output

```
Module acronym_list
  def self.included(other)
     include SAXMachine
     SAXMachine.configure(other) do |c|

        c.element :metadata, :class => metadata
        c.element :info, :class => info
     end
  end


  class metadata
    include SAXMachine

    c.element :release
    c.element :id
    c.element :checkdigit
    c.element :status
    c.element :date_added
    c.element :date_modified
    c.element :language
    c.element :license_url
  end

  class info
    include SAXMachine

    c.element :name
  end

end
```

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks! If I wanted to make the processing of the item element generic (i.e. I have one file with acronym_item and another with asset_item), can I take a similar approach with modes, like you've done above?

Comment: Well in the sample you have posted there is an `acronym_list` element, but no `acronym_item` so I am not sure where `asset_item` would appear. And it's not clear which output you want. If nothing changes in terms of the wanted output structure then it should suffice to simply provide an enumeration of match patterns for the templates e.g. `<xsl:template match="acs:acronym_list | acs:asset_list">...</xsl:template>`. Modes are helpful to process a node several times i.e. the first time for outputting in one way in a certain way using the first mode, the second time for outputting in a second way